# Elasticsearch Filter on Dynamic Value

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am completely new to ELK stack.
I am using a filter like **field1:value1** and get back documents as results. On 1 of those returned documents there are **field2:value2**, I am interested in **field2:value2** and would like to filter further on that. So **value2** kind of dynamic, i.e not known ahead of time. The final result I want is all documents returned from **field1** and **field2**

Is there a way to make a filter to do that automatically, i.e I just have to input **value1** and it will filter, find **value2** and filter once again and finally return all documents from both filter actions?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can use `_exists_:<field>` on kibana to filter documents that have that field.

```
field1:value1 AND __exist__:field2 AND field:value2
```

Comment: No, it is more like: `field1:value1 OR field2:value2`
But **value2** is not known yet. I am looking for ways to automatically retrieve **value2** from `field1:value1` filter, and then use it with above filter.